# operator == overload for double linked list

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I have realized Double Linked List. And now i need to overload == operator.

dll.cpp:67:17: error: expected expression
            if ([ind] != sp[ind]) {

The problem i don't understand how to overload == operator if only one parameter is given. I mean if i write bool operator ==(DLL sp1, DLL sp2){} compiler says `error: overloaded 'operator==' must be a binary operator (has 3 parameters)`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class DLL {
public:
    DLL(){
        size = 0;
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
    }
    T operator [](int ind) {
        int counter = 0;
        T res = T();
        Node *cur = this->head;
        while(cur != nullptr) {
            if(counter == ind) {
                res = cur->data;
            }
            cur = cur->next;
            counter++;
        }
        return res;
    }
    bool operator ==(DLL<int> sp){
        bool isequal = true;
        for(int ind = 0; ind < sp.length(); ind++){
            if ([ind] != sp[ind]) {
                isequal = false;
            }
        }
        return isequal;

    }
    void clear() {
        while(size != 1)
            pop_front();
        delete tail;
        size--;
    }
    int length() {return size;}
    }
private:
    class Node{
    public:
        T data;
        Node *next;
        Node *prev;
        Node(T data = T(), Node *prev= nullptr, Node *next = nullptr) {
            this->data = data;
            this->next = next;
            this->prev = prev;
        }
    };
    int size;
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing the right thing for the most part.

The problem that is causing this error:

> dll.cpp:67:17: error: expected expression if ([ind] != sp[ind]) {

is that you actually want to do this instead:

```
*this[ind] != sp[ind]
```

Also, there appears to be an extra `}` right here:

```
int length() {return size;}
} // <- not exactly sure what that's about, but I don't think you need it.
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you have it defined as a member function (and it only takes list of int for some reason (you should probably remove the `<int>`).

```
bool operator ==(DLL<int> sp);   // There is a small issue in that you
                                 // passing by value and thus causing a copy.

                                 // Another issue with this is that it should
                                 // probably marked "const" to indicate state
                                 // is not changed by the call.
```

When the compiler see's this.

```
list1 == list2
```

This is simply syntactic sugar for:

```
list1.operator==(list2);
```

Thus is why you only need one parameter when you declare it as a member function. The alternative is to declare it as a friend function.

```
friend bool operator ==(DLL<T> const& lhs, DLL<T> const& rhs);
```

In this case it is a free standing function. When the compiler sees:

```
list1 == list2
```

This is syntactic sugar for:

```
operator==(list1, list2)
```

The problem was that you were defining a member function with two parameters. The left hand side is the class object and then you were expecting two objects on the right hand side (but the == operator only has one place on the right). That is why it is complaining about three parameters.

So the real question is should it be a member or a friend.

It does not matter here.

There are situations where it "can".

Example: If your class contains a single argument constructor (lets say you could create a list from an integer) and you use a member `operator==()`

```
 DLL<int>    list;

 if (list == 5) {
 }
```

This will now compile. Because your member operator uses a parameter and the compiler can convert an integer into the DLL parameter using a single argument constructor.

The counter argument to this is that normally you don't want automatic conversions of your type so you should mark single argument constructors as `explicit` to prevent this.

So:

If you class can automatically be created via a one argument constructor (most cases this is not true but it can be).

Then you should prefer a friend function version.

otherwise it does not matter and I would probably fall towards the member function.

Answer (score 0):

A comparison operator is a binary operator that treats both the operands equally, it is advisable to make it a friend function and not a member.

So the declaration for the function would change to

```
friend bool operator ==(const DLL<int> & lhs, const DLL<int> & rhs);
```

You can choose to define it inside or outside the class.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421729/602798) on when you need to make an operator member vs non-member.

Comment: you should also adress the `T` vs `int` issue. If OP adds this to the class declaration then `DLL<T>` will be befriended with the operator for  `DLL<int>` which isnt really the right thing to do